How to get each average of multiple items?
There is a table storing name, speed and timestamp of cars. Each car sends its speed at irregular time intervals, some send more often, some may have not sent their data for a couple of hours, simplified example (real table has 20 cars and roughly 3000 lines each):



name
speed
timestamp




yellow
100
1707532681


yellow
110
1707532661


yellow
120
1707532621


yellow
110
1707532631


yellow
140
1707532681


red
100
1707432681


red
120
1707332681


red
150
1707232681


red
170
1707532681



I would like to get the average speed for each car for their individual (!) last 24 hours. I am struggling to get that into a single SQL-statement. Have tried with multiple SELECT and IN, MAX and AVG functions without luck. Any help is appreciated.
I have tried to get the MAX of each car:
SELECT name, MAX(timestamp) AS s FROM data GROUP BY name
And put this into another SELECT:
SELECT AVG(speed) FROM data WHERE (name, timestamp) IN (SELECT name, MAX(timestamp) AS s FROM data GROUP BY name) AND timestamp > s - 86400
But the latter is breaking because s is unknown - of course it is. How do I get it into the other SELECT then? I need the MAX value of each timestamp because each car has its own last speed measurement from which it should go 24 hours back and calculate the average. Hope this makes it more clear.

Can you also specify the expected result, i.e. provide a complete [mcve].

The timestamp provided here, Is that a Unix timestamp?

Have you tried a GROUP BY? Show us your latest query attempt.

@jarlh: thank you for reformatting, I did it, but it didnt work. expected result? "average speed for each car for their individual last 24 hours", means: two values for each car: its name and its average speed. sorry, I dont understand your question. my query attempts dont work. of course I have tried with GROUP BY. as I said: no luck.

@wandering-geek: yes!

To get average speed need some time range.. what is your time range ? Please explain in details and give mannual output ... @Døner M.

If you just want the name and the average speed for the 24 hours up to the most recent report, you can use GROUP BY and MAX to get the most recent timestamp and a correlated subquery for the average speed:
SELECT
  name,
  (SELECT AVG(speed) FROM data WHERE name = d.name AND timestamp >= (MAX(d.timestamp) - 86400)) AS avg_speed_24h
FROM data d
GROUP BY name;

Alternatively, if you want the full set of rows as provided by wandering-geek, there is no need to convert from unix timestamps:
SELECT
  name,
  AVG(speed) OVER (
    PARTITION BY name
    ORDER BY `timestamp`
    RANGE BETWEEN 86400 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS avg_speed_24h
FROM data;

Here's a db<>fiddle.
Note: The average of some point in time speeds does not give you a meaningful average speed. For that you would need distance travelled and time taken.

thank you. I dont know about the above (all throw errors), but there is one at your fiddle-example that is working perfectly: SELECT
name,
(SELECT AVG(speed) FROM data WHERE name = d.name AND timestamp >= (MAX(d.timestamp) - 86400)) AS avg_speed_24h
FROM data d
GROUP BY name;

The query "that is working perfectly" is the first of the two queries shown in my answer. If the Window function based queries aren't working for you, it suggests you are running an unsupported version of MySQL and you should consider upgrading to 8.x.

indeed, you are right. thank you for the quick help!

Assuming the table name is Table. Also assuming this is a MySQL database, because of the tag in your question.
First let's create a CTE where we create a new column where we convert from UNIX timestamp to a standard one, using the MySQL function FROM_UNIXTIME()
WITH processed AS (
SELECT name, speed, FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`) AS report_timestamp
FROM Table
)

Note: Since timestamp is a keyword, the column name will need to escaped using backticks.
Now, since we have the data - including timestamp - in the format we need, let's solve the problem. We can do this using Window Functions.
Although the caveat here is that the average speed will be calculated for each row of the data.
For this, as per your question, we will calculate the average speed, for each car, for the last 24 hours from the timestamp available on the current row. For this we will use the RANGE clause to specify the frame definition, which in this case is the previous 1 day.
Let's use the above CTE as the source table.
SELECT 
 *,
 AVG(speed) OVER(
    PARTITION BY name
    ORDER BY report_timestamp ASC
    RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 1 DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
   ) AS avg_speed_24h
FROM processed;


select *,
  round(avg(speed) over ( partition by name), 2) as 'avg_byColumn_Name',
  round(avg(speed) over ( partition by name order by timestamp), 2) as 'avg_byColumn_Name&TimeStamp'
from T;

Get output: db<>fiddle

